# Android application to convert Image to Text

Tags: android, performance, android-ndk, android-camera, tesseract

I am trying to develop android application that converts Image to Text using tess-two library, following this tutorial:

http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/

but the application gets closed after the picture is taken.

My code is:

```
protected Button _button;
protected ImageView _image;
protected TextView _field;
protected String _path;
protected boolean _taken;

protected static final String PHOTO_TAKEN = "photo_taken";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    _image = ( ImageView ) findViewById( R.id.imageView1 );
    _field = ( TextView ) findViewById( R.id.textView1 );
    _button = ( Button ) findViewById( R.id.button1 );


    _path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/ImageOCR/make_machine_example.jpg";

    _button.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startCameraActivity();
        }
    } );
}

protected void startCameraActivity()
{
    File file = new File( _path );
    Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile( file );

    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );
    intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri );

    startActivityForResult( intent, 0 );
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{   
    Log.i( "MakeMachine", "resultCode: " + resultCode );
    switch( resultCode )
    {
        case 0:
            Log.i( "MakeMachine", "User cancelled" );
            break;

        case -1:
            onPhotoTaken();
            break;
    }
}

protected void onPhotoTaken() 
{
    _taken = true;

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 2;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile( _path, options );
    _image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    _field.setVisibility( View.GONE );

    //--------------------------------------------------------

    ExifInterface exif;
    try {
        exif = new ExifInterface(_path);

        int exifOrientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
        int rotate = 0;

        switch (exifOrientation) {
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
            rotate = 90;
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
            rotate = 180;
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
            rotate = 270;
            break;
        }

        if (rotate != 0) {
            int w = bitmap.getWidth();
            int h = bitmap.getHeight();

            // Setting pre rotate
            Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
            mtx.preRotate(rotate);
         // Rotating Bitmap & convert to ARGB_8888, required by tess
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, false);

        }

        bitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        String DATA_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/tesseract/";
        String lang = "eng";
        TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
        baseApi.init(DATA_PATH, lang);

        baseApi.setImage(bitmap);
        String recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();
        Toast.makeText(this, recognizedText, 4000).show();
        baseApi.end();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    //---------------------------------------------------
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState( Bundle outState ) {
    outState.putBoolean( MainActivity.PHOTO_TAKEN , _taken );
}

@Override 
protected void onRestoreInstanceState( Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    Log.i( "MakeMachine", "onRestoreInstanceState()");
    if( savedInstanceState.getBoolean( MainActivity.PHOTO_TAKEN ) ) {
        onPhotoTaken();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

the path for the English language data is shown here:

```
    /storage/sdcard0/tesseract/tessdata
```

and the logCat window is displaying the following logs:

```
    03-20 02:24:25.094: D/libEGL(32009): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
    03-20 02:24:25.104: D/libEGL(32009): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
    03-20 02:24:25.104: D/libEGL(32009): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
    03-20 02:24:25.109: D/(32009): Device driver API match
    03-20 02:24:25.109: D/(32009): Device driver API version: 10
    03-20 02:24:25.109: D/(32009): User space API version: 10 
    03-20 02:24:25.109: D/(32009): mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Tue Oct     16 15:37:13 KST 2012 
    03-20 02:24:25.144: D/OpenGLRenderer(32009): Enabling debug mode 0
    03-20 02:24:33.689: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(32009): showStatusIcon on inactive   InputConnection
    03-20 02:24:41.469: I/MakeMachine(32009): resultCode: -1
    03-20 02:24:41.469: I/System.out(32009): Not a DRM File, opening notmally
    03-20 02:24:41.469: I/System.out(32009): buffer returned 
    03-20 02:24:41.499: D/dalvikvm(32009): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 60K, 8% free 12302K/13319K, paused 25ms, total 26ms
    03-20 02:24:41.514: I/dalvikvm-heap(32009): Grow heap (frag case) to 20.515MB for   7990288-byte allocation
    03-20 02:24:41.534: D/dalvikvm(32009): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3K, 5% free 20101K/21127K, paused 12ms+2ms, total 22ms
    03-20 02:24:41.534: D/dalvikvm(32009): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 6ms
    03-20 02:24:41.959: D/dalvikvm(32009): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 37K, 5% free 20077K/21127K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
    03-20 02:24:41.989: I/dalvikvm-heap(32009): Grow heap (frag case) to 28.108MB for  7990288-byte allocation
    03-20 02:24:42.019: D/dalvikvm(32009): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 4% free 27880K/28935K, paused 13ms+2ms, total 27ms
    03-20 02:24:42.019: D/dalvikvm(32009): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 14ms
    03-20 02:24:42.134: D/dalvikvm(32009): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 4% free 27880K/28935K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
    03-20 02:24:42.144: I/dalvikvm-heap(32009): Grow heap (frag case) to 35.728MB for 7990288-byte allocation
    03-20 02:24:42.174: D/dalvikvm(32009): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 3% free 35683K/36743K, paused 12ms+2ms, total 28ms
    03-20 02:24:42.174: D/dalvikvm(32009): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 1ms
    03-20 02:24:42.189: D/dalvikvm(32009): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.example.imageocr/lib/liblept.so 0x42664f40
    03-20 02:24:42.199: D/dalvikvm(32009): Added shared lib /data/data/com.example.imageocr/lib/liblept.so 0x42664f40
    03-20 02:24:42.204: D/dalvikvm(32009): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.example.imageocr/lib/libtess.so 0x42664f40
    03-20 02:24:42.259: D/dalvikvm(32009): Added shared lib /data/data/com.example.imageocr/lib/libtess.so 0x42664f40
    03-20 02:24:42.259: I/Tesseract(native)(32009): Attempting Init() with dir=/storage/sdcard0/tesseract/, lang=eng
    03-20 02:24:42.269: A/libc(32009): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread        32009 (xample.imageocr)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use another app to capture an image by camera and convert it into text,  you may use my app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sunbulmh.ocr

Here is a sample code that you can use in your app to get OCR service:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
try {
    pm.getPackageInfo("sunbulmh.ocr", PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
    Intent LaunchIntent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("sunbulmh.ocr");
    LaunchIntent.setFlags(0);
    startActivityForResult(LaunchIntent,5);
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    Uri URLURI = Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sunbulmh.ocr");
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,URLURI);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Then, get the result in onActivityResult():

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if(requestCode == 5){
            String ocr_txt = data.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
            // ocr_txt contains the recognized text.




        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please summarize or quote the relevant parts of your linked content so your answer is still useful if the link gets broken.